# How to configure rails to serialize datetime to json always in utc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Is it possible to configure rails to serialize datetime to json always in utc without timezone?

For example: instead "2011-06-15T21:40:05+06:00"  i want "2011-06-15T15:40:05+00:00"

Comment: You can configure Rails to always use UTC or any other time zone in application.rb file (this would concern all application and database). http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: I've been trying a similar thing:

`Time.use_zone('Etc/UTC') { MyModel.to_json }`

This appears to work in the console, but still do the wrong time zone in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the time zone for the entire application add this line to `environment.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

To set the time-zone before a render call

```
Time.zone = 'UTC'    
render
```

**Note**: These instructions pertains to Rails 2.3x

Comment: >> config.time_zone = 'UTC' haven't solved problem. im using rails 3